# get selected date of richfaces calendar in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jsf, richfaces

I have two calendars in the same form, both `rich:calendar`. One is the *start date* (or activation date) the other one the *end date* (or deactivation date).

What I am trying to achieve is to mark the selected *start date* in the *end date* calendar.

For example:

[image]

here July 14 (in red) is the *start date* and July 16 the currently selected *end date*.

My problem seems to be, that I can't get the value of *start date* via JQuery. I tried "hiding" the value somewhere on the page so I could access it with `$('#myForm\\:hiddenActivationDate').val();` and it almost worked.. but then everything else stopped working.

These are the script functions I wrote:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
function activationDateDisablementFunction(day) {
    return currentDate.getDate() <= day.date.getDate();
}
function activationDateClassProv(day) {
    if (currentDate.getDate() > day.date.getDate()) {
        return "disabledDay";
    }
}
function deactivationDateDisablementFunction(day) {
    var hiddenActivationDate = $('#myForm\\:hiddenActivationDate').val();
    var activationDate = new Date(Date.parse(hiddenActivationDate));
    return day.date.getDate() >= activationDate.getDate(); // true = enabled, false =disabled
}
function deactivationDateClassProv(day) {
    var hiddenActivationDate = $('#myForm\\:hiddenActivationDate').val();
    var activationDate = new Date(Date.parse(hiddenActivationDate));
    if (day.date.getDate() < activationDate.getDate()) {
        return "disabledDay";
    }
    if (day.date.getDate() === activationDate.getDate()) {
        return "activatedDay";
    }
}
```

and here the two calendars:

```
<!-- start date -->
<a4j:outputPanel id="activationDateCalendar" layout="block" >
    <rich:calendar value="#{myBean.activationDate}"
                   popup="true"     
                   datePattern="#{myBean.dateFormat}"     
                   boundaryDatesMode="scroll"    
                   jointPoint="bottomAuto"
                   showWeeksBar="false"
                   showApplyButton="false" 
                   dayClassFunction="activationDateClassProv" 
                   dayDisableFunction="activationDateDisablementFunction"
                   style="width:320px">
        <a4j:ajax render="@this, hiddenActivationDate, deactivationDateCalendar,  activationDatePreview, deactivationDatePreview, durationPreview" />
    </rich:calendar>
</a4j:outputPanel>

<!-- my hidden date -->
<h:inputHidden id="hiddenActivationDate" value="#{myBean.activationDate}" />

<!-- end date -->
<a4j:outputPanel id="deactivationDateCalendar" layout="block" >
    <rich:calendar value="#{myBean.deactivationDate}"
                   popup="true"     
                   datePattern="#{myBean.dateFormat}"     
                   boundaryDatesMode="scroll"    
                   jointPoint="bottomAuto"
                   showWeeksBar="false"
                   showApplyButton="false"
                   dayClassFunction="activationDateClassProv" 
                   dayDisableFunction="activationDateDisablementFunction"
                   style="width:320px">
        <a4j:ajax render="@this, activationDatePreview, deactivationDatePreview, durationPreview" />                           
    </rich:calendar>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

**in short**
what I want to do is access the *start date* value from within the JQuery function `deactivationDateClassProv` directly without getting it from a hidden field.

Is this possible? Or is there a "Richfaces way" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RichFaces components have a JS API, read the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html_single/#sect-Component_Reference-calendar-JavaScript_API).

In your case you access the date simply by:

```
function deactivationDateClassProv(day) {
    var hiddenActivationDate = #{rich:component('firstCalendarId')}.getValue();
    …
}
```

Note that the function is only called when needed, if you just close and open the calendar it will not be called again (unless you switch months or set `isRendered` to false).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what  I needed! And thanks for pointing out, that the function won't be called again. I am curious if it will pose any problems ..